# Launch an App on Samsung Smart TV startup

Tags: scheduling, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I want to automatically launch an app on TV startup.
i.e. when the user power on the TV, TV will powerup and my app will start

Comment: It's impossible with original Samsung Smart TV SDK.

Comment: Ohh... is there any work around to solve this? currently i am trying with openAPI (web api) to get an android app to power up the tv and the launch my app. highly appreciate comments on that too. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can do this by following steps :

1. Create a Ticker Application and in the config file of the widget add this code

> `<ticker itemtype="boolean">y</ticker>`

y - for auto ticker launch and 
n - for not launching.

2. Than goto to Menu->smartHub->AppSettings->AutoTicker and turn auto ticker ON.[image: Menu of Samsung Smart TV]

[image: Auto Ticker Options]

Note: This feature is only available for selective regions.

Comment: Thank you for the update... yes this is much easier than relying on a 3rd client.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but only for 2012+ TV/BD models, using Convergence and Multi-Screen APIs. 
Take a look at:

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00027/index.html

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/d30/index.html

Comment: Thank you so much @andrea-f.. Sorry for the delayed reply. Will definitely look in to them and post an update..

Comment: How are either of these links relevant?

Comment: Because you can launch an app through the NScreen API and Convergence

Comment: Can you describe implementation or provide sample? Both technologies relies on external client in same local network. How can they be used to start app on TV startup?

Comment: Any samples? Or describe base idea?

Answer (score 1):

You  have to create "[Ticker app](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tec00124/index.html)". But you have to be careful with keys (there are some differences all keys as default app is not supported)

But You have to enable ticker app in your tv. If you cannot enable it then you go to the service menu and enable hotel mode. Then it should select ticker app in smart tv menu.

M.

Comment: I've read that ticker app autostart is only available in US and Korea regions. If I am able to enable hotel mode in a european Samsung smart TV, will I be able to enable auto start on TV boot of a ticker application?

Comment: Yes, In hotel mode you can run app as ticker app.

Comment: Is there any difference on how this ticker application can be added between the hotel mode and regular mode (any specifics for EU Samsung TVs)?

Comment: You can add you app to the TV with using youw webserver (widgetlist.xml) or directly from USB stick. I think that ticker app cannot be uploaded to the EU Samsung Store...